# Package ‘survIDINRI’ error: Error in Surv(xi, di) : Time variable is not numeric

Tags: r

```
Train1 <- subset(Train,select=c("Survivalmonths","specific","Age","Sex","Tumor_size","T_stage","Grade", "Radiation","Surgery","Chemotherapy","LNR","RNP","RNE"))

Train1$Survivalmonths <- as.integer(Train1$Survivalmonths)
Train1 <- subset(Train1,Train1$Survivalmonths>0) 

library(survIDINRI)
t0 = 120
indata0 <-  as.matrix(subset(Train1,select = c("Survivalmonths","specific","Age","Sex","Tumor_size","T_stage","Grade", "Radiation","Surgery","Chemotherapy","LNR")))
indata1 <-  as.matrix(subset(Train1,select = c("Survivalmonths","specific","Age","Sex","Tumor_size","T_stage","Grade","Radiation","Surgery","Chemotherapy","RNP"))) 
covs0 <- as.matrix(indata0[,c(-1,-2)])
covs1 <- as.matrix(indata1[,c(-1,-2)])

x<-IDI.INF(Train1[,1:2],covs0, covs1, t0, npert=10)
IDI.INF.OUT(x)

#Error in Surv(xi, di) : Time variable is not numeric
```

Comment: Please add text to your question and provide a reproducible example ( you need to add your dataset here- u can use dput() function to do so). to help you, we should be able just to copy paste your code in out console and click run- so we can reproduce the error you see

Comment: Because of the data is big, dput() function does not work well. I loaded the data in my github:https://github.com/JinShiny/survdata. And the code was copied. Please help me. Thanks again.
str(d$specific)
str(d$Survivalmonths)

t0 = 120
Y <- Train[,c("Survivalmonths","specific")]
z.old = as.matrix(Train[,c("Age","Sex")])
z.new = as.matrix(Train[,c("Age","Sex","Race","Laterality")])

X <- IDI.INF(d[,5:6],z.old,z.new,t0,npert=200)
IDI.INF.OUT(X)

Comment: df=read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JinShiny/survdata/main/d.csv") to make it reproducible. teh dataset you provided do not have columns Columns `Tumor_size`, `T_stage`, `Grade`, `Radiation`, `Surgery`, etc. don't exist. as you list here:Train1 <- subset(Train,select=c("Survivalmonths","specific","Age","Sex","Tumor_size","T_stage","Grade", "Radiation","Surgery","Chemotherapy","LNR","RNP","RNE"))

Comment: please update the code so it works

Comment: Sorry about it. For the sake of data security of the subject group, I have only filtered a few columns of data as an example. The reason for error reporting is the same. The new data and code are also in the Github I uploaded. Thanks again.

Comment: i still unable to reproduce your code. can you first create a new r script that starts with this line: df=read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JinShiny/survdata/main/d.csv"), and then add your code and make sure it can be run to reproduce your error

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I sent an E-mail to the author(Prof. Hajime; huno@ds.dfci.harvard.edu) of the package. He gave me the guidlence. And the code worked successfully.

Comment: please still update your code and post the solution- in case others will face similar issue- they can see what you have done to resolve it